# How to protect a pointer's address that an user outside the class can modify? c++

Tags: c++, multithreading, pointers, locking

I have a buffer that will sent the pointer to read the data directly to do zero copy. But how can I protect the address pointer from code outside the class?

```
 const void * returnReadPointer(size_t arraySize)
 {
     if ( arraySize < MemoryUsageInArray)
         {return array + arrayIndex}
     else{ return null} 
 }
```

The return pointer can access the array which is the buffer. I want to try to protect it from improper usage.

Comment: Can you please be more clear in what you want to ask? Also post your code so that everybody can look into it.

Comment: What do you mean by zero copy?

Comment: I posted a little piece. The function has direct access the the read pointer.

Comment: Zero copy means  that the function that uses the data off the buffer will read directly from the array without making copies to other locations. I.E. we do not copy onto a new value and delete the data. The data will simply get overwritten if we loop around.

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "improper usage". You can use smart pointer, specifically `std::unique_ptr` to make sure there's only one owner who's managing the pointer.

Comment: What's improper usage to you?

Answer (score 1):

If you hand the address of a memory location to your client, they can do anything with it. Change your API and instead of returning an address, provide only the functionality they will need:

```
<your_type> readValue(size_t index)
{
     // index validation etc.
     .
     .

     return array[index];
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Make the return value a `const void *`.

```
const void * returnReadPointer(size_t arraySize)
```

Comment: I tried that but someone said I need to still protect the address the pointer points to.

Answer (score 0):

You can change the function prototype as below to protect your pointer from being changed.

`const void * const returnReadPointer(size_t arraySize)`

Comment: A `const` qualified variable can be assigned to a non `const` variable and this effectively does nothing.

Comment: this isn't a const-qualified variable, but a pointer to such.